# Java Servlet как сделать logout?

Tags: java, servlet

Не могу коректно реализовать завершение сессии пользователя. После нажатия кнопки бек меня возвращает на авторизированное окно. Как сбросить сессию? Пробовал через фильтры тоде не получается.
В логауте уже наворотив всего что можно.

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    String message = "Вы успешно вышли.";

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
            cookies[i].setValue(null);
            cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
            resp.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }

    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
    resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
    resp.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward
    session.removeAttribute("name");
    session.invalidate();
    req.getSession(true);

    RequestDispatcher rs = req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp");
    req.setAttribute("message", message);
    rs.forward(req, resp);
}
```

}

Comment: Нашел готовое решение http://atozjavatutorials.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-create-login-and-logout-program-in.html

Answer (score 1):

После нажатия кнопки "назад" браузер берет страницу из внутренного кэша. Иногда это даже отдельный особый кэш исключительно для кнопок "Назад" и "Вперед".

Попробуйте после нажатия кнопки "Назад" обновить страницу.

Comment: Тогда даже session.атрибут возвращается и можно ходить по разным вкладкам.